# ASP.NETでHTTPリクエストごとに使用するappsettings.jsonオプションを変更するベストな方法はありますか？

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET Coreでオプションをappsettings.jsonから読み込んでいます。（ASPが素人です）
使用するオプションをHTTPリクエストのパラメータにより変更したいのですが、ベストな方法はあるでしょうか？
一応動かすことはできたのですが、改善したい点があり質問します。

例えばappsettings.jsonが、

```js
{
  "params":[
    "a":{
      "name": "Alice"
    },
    "b":{
      "inherit": true
    }
  ],
  "default":{
    "name": "Default"
  }
}
```

オプションクラスが、

```cs
public class ExampleOptions {
  public const string Example = "Example";
  public string? Name { get; set; }
  public bool? Inherit { get; set; }
}
```

使用クラスが、

```cs
public class Example {
  ExampleOptions m_options;
  public Example(IOptions<ExampleOptions> options) { /*固定じゃないのを明示するためにIOptionsSnapshotにしたい*/
    m_options = options.Value;
  }
}
```

登録が、

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] arg) {
  return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) => {
           services.AddScope(provider => {
             return GetParamExampleOptions<ExampleOptions>(
               hostContext.Configuration,
               provider,
               ExampleOptions.Example); });
         })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
           webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
         });
}
public static IOptions GetParamExampleOptions<T>(
  IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider provider, string sectionName) {
  var context = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
  var param = context.HttpContext!.GetRouteData().Values["param"] as string;
  var options = configuration.GetSection($"params:{param}:{sectionName}").Get<T>():
  var inMemoryOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  //ここでInheritがtrueなら、"default"のパラメータをコピーしたインメモリオプションを生成
  //実際は複数のOptionでInheritの機能を使うため文字列操作で統一したほうが楽と思い複雑になってる
  var inheritedOptions = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(inMemoryOptions)
    .Build().GetSection($"params:{param}:{sectionName}");
  return Options.Create(inheritedOptions); /*ここでIOptionsSnapshotを作りたい*/
}
```

これで一応リクエストごとにオプションを変えながら動くことはできるのですが、`IOptions`ではなく`IOptionsSnapshot`を使いたいと考えています。

`servicies.AddOptions()`で登録すれば、使用側が`IOptions`でも`IOptionsSnapshot`でも自動で切り替えてくれるのですが、リクエストごとに切り替わるオプションの指定方法がわかりませんでした。

`Inherit`でDefaultオプションを継承してる機能があるため、複雑になってるかもしれません。
同等の他の方法でもいいので、よりスマートな実装をご存じの方いらっしゃらないでしょうか？

Comment: Core は asp.net-core というタグがあるのでそちらをつけた方がよさそうです。「HTTPリクエストのパラメータ」というのは具体的に何でしょう？

Comment: 「スマート」の優劣は、何で判断しているのですか？

Comment: そもそも何をしたいのでしょう？　質問に書かれた appsettings.json から想像するにユーザー固有の情報のように思えますが、もしそうだとすると、プロファイル情報から取得するなど別の方法を考えた方が良さそうです。XY問題になってないでしょうか？

Comment: >「HTTPリクエストのパラメータ」というのは具体的に何でしょう？
<--
Getパラメータを受け取り、プロジェクトの切り替えに使用するのを想定しています。

Comment: >「スマート」の優劣は、何で判断しているのですか？ <-- コード数が少ないや自作クラスではなく用意されている汎用クラスの機能を使うなど、プロジェクト外の人でもC#を知っていれば読むのが楽なものが好みです。

Comment: >そもそも何をしたいのでしょう？ <-- Getパラメータをもとに設定を読み込むプロジェクトを切り替え、リクエストごとに設定変更を検知して適用したいです。（時には新規プロジェクトの設定追加したい。）もともと引き継いだソースコードのため、変更量を少なくしたいというのもあります。

Answer (score -1):

IOptionsからIOptionsSnapshotに変更することはできましたので一旦解決済みとしたいと思います。

```
return Options.Create(inheritedOptions); /*ここでIOptionsSnapshotを作りたい*/
```

これを、下記のように（IOptionsと）IOptionsSnapshotの派生先であるOptionsManagerを使うようにしました。

```
return new OptionsManager<T>(
    new OptionsFactory<T>(
        new IConfigureOptions<T>[]
        {
            new ConfigureOptions<T>(opt =>
            {
                inheritedOptions.Bind(opt); /* Bind()があるのに気付いたため解決 */
            })
        },
        Enumerable.Empty<IPostConfigureOptions<T>>()
    )
);
```

みなさんご確認ありがとうございました。